# añadir una clase al nodo anterior con js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bien, me tope con un problema.

Tengo dentro de un div `padre`, dos elementos. Uno es un `div` llamémoslo `hijo_1` y el otro es un `ul` que seria el `hijo_2`.

El problema, es que estoy posicionado en el nodo `hijo 2` y lo que quiero es añadirle al `hijo_1` una clase llamada `arrow`, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

¿Alguna idea?

```
<li class="Padre" >
    <div class="hijo_1">    
        <a href="#" class="nav__link open" ><i class="far fa-chart-pie"></i> &nbsp;Estadisticas</a>
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/main/svg-icon/arrow.svg') }}" class="list__arrow">
    </div>
    <ul class="hijo_2">
        <li class="list__inside">
             <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Estoy dentro</a>
        </li>

        <li class="list__inside">
             <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Estoy dentro</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas posicionado en el `hijo_2`, para acceder al `hijo_1` adyacente simplemente `previousElementSibling`. Checa más detalles [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling).

```js
// Estás en el hijo_2
const hijo_2 = document.querySelector(".hijo_2")

// Selecciona el elemento adyacente anterior usando previousElementSibling
const hijo_1 = hijo_2.previousElementSibling

//Agrega la clase arrow al elemento adyacente anterior
hijo_1.classList.add("arrow")
```

```css
.arrow{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="Padre" >
    <div class="hijo_1">    
        <a href="#" class="nav__link open" ><i class="far fa-chart-pie"></i> &nbsp;Estadisticas</a>
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/main/svg-icon/arrow.svg') }}" class="list__arrow">
    </div>
    <ul class="hijo_2">
        <li class="list__inside">
             <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Estoy dentro</a>
        </li>

        <li class="list__inside">
             <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Estoy dentro</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: Sip, justamente habia encontrado la solucion tambien. Muchas gracias... me funcionó como dijiste